# Passing special chars to exe through command prompt

Tags: dos

I want to pass mix of most of all special chars a one command line arguments to an exe. The exe is invoked by bat file.

syntax is something like this:

### sample.bat file

set arg1="newData!@#$%%^&*()(**)://///;><|+=-"

MyPath="D:\MyExeLocation"
%MyPath%\MyExe.exe %arg1%

Above one is working but it's not working if i add double quote (") in the arg1 string. would you please tell me how to escape it. I tried escaping it by ^, " and \ also. it's not working. if i do with \, string includes \ as well along with double quote. other two ^ and " are not working throwing some error

Ultimately i want to pass any special chars in arg1. Would you please give me your suggestions???

Advance Thanks
Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the single quote I old you. I've used this in a XML file. Nevermind.

You must double the double quote if you want a single double quote. For example if you want to pass the string "a" to your application you must use """a""" as parameter.

For testing the parameters I use the following bat file

```
set var=%*

c:\cmd.exe %var%
```

and cmd.exe is a the following C# program

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);

            foreach (var s in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Petar Petrov, would you give me an example of how to do it. if i enclose arg by single quote i am getting errors like > unexpected at this time and | unexpected at this time...and so on

Comment: how to pass argument with hyfen (-) as first char and convert it as literal??                                                              ex: set arg1="-newData!@#$%%^&()(*)://///;><|+=-"

MyPath="D:\MyExeLocation" %MyPath%\MyExe.exe %arg1%        --This statement is not getting executed as it treats first letter hyfen as switch char. It would be great if you can give some tips to solve this???